# delete specific number of files with python

Tags: python

I have a folder where want to delete the files on it when they reaches 5 files (or if they are older than 5 days). so far I have tried this:

```
path_file = r'C:\...\new folder'
files = os.listdir(path_file)
for file in files [:5]:
    os.remove(file)
```

This code gives the next error:

```
os.remove(file)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified file
```

Comment: post more context

Comment: `C:\...\new folder` is invalid Windows path though

Comment: try `print(file)` in your loop and see what you're actually dealing with

Comment: @OlvinRoght the code uses a raw string literal, and the `...` presumably stands for something that was omitted for privacy. The code is fine.

Comment: Hint: if I told you that I live in apartment #123, would you be able to come visit me? What other information would you need, in order to find the place?

Answer (score 0):

Add path to the filename

```
path= r'C:\...\new folder' 
files = os.listdir(path_file) 
for file in files [:5]: 
    os.remove(path + "\\" + file)
```

Comment: It's better to use `os.path.join()` instead.